# Reuse a shared controller's functionality which maintains seperate state for each page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I want to have a simple controller that is reused in most of my pages, specifically a sortBy controller that allows one to decided which column to sort by and rather to sort by ascending or descending order in any of our list views.

I imagine this would not be hard to do.  I can have my shared template file add a sort div which uses some sortController.

However, I want to maintain this state, so if someone leaves my People page to visit my tasks page and comes back later their selection for sort order on the people page should be maintained.  The standard way to maintain state is to use a service, as we have done for other things.  However, I'm trying to reuse as much functionality as possible, having to define a half dozen near-identical services, one for each page, feels sloppy.

Is there a cleaner way to define a single service and ensure that a separate state is used for each page?

One option I an think of is to have a service with a basic map, mapping the page name, or controller, to it's own state object.  The sortController could then call sortState.get(pageName) (or something like that) to get the specific state it wants, generating a new one if the request page doesn't exist yet.

However, I don't know if this is the cleanest approach.  Is there a better way to reuse a controllers, maybe some angular provider I'm forgetting about?

as a related question what is the cleanest way to provide my shared sortController with a reference the list it's sorting and what columns I want to sort by for a given list?

edit: I'm using ui-router, so each 'page' is a different base abstract state for a url.

Comment: I set a site wide controller on my body or wrapper tag that allows child controllers to inherit. Something like `body ng-controller="SiteCtrl><div ng-view></div></body>` Not sure if this will handle your use case.

Comment: You can always just have your controllers inherit directly from the base controller if you so desire.

Comment: @dsollen - Is this a table you are presenting the data in? If so, then I have some ready made code that might help you out.

Comment: @Josh we will be sorting both tables and grids version of the view, with the grid version being more important.  This means the ability to select sorting has to be done via some drop down, not (just) tied into the table columns name like most tables handle sorting now of days; since the grid view doesn't have column names.

Comment: @dsollen - That makes sense. Regardless, I think a directive, or set of directives would probably work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest this really sounds like the perfect place for a directive with a controller. Assuming these are different templates, you could apply the directive with a name attribute in order to preserve state.

```
<column-sort-chooser name="myNamedState" list="ctrl.myList" />
```

There are a million ways you could store the state, but an easy option is to simply use the built in [`$cacheFactory`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory)

```
var stateCache = $cacheFactory("sortstate:" + attrs.name);

//Get current state or create a new one
var currentState = stateCache.get('sortInfo') || {};

//do some stuff with state making sure to persist for each operation
stateCache.set('sortInfo', currentState);
```

This way you don't have to create a seperate service, and the directive can handle loading and persisting the state each time it is loaded up.

Comment: hmm, both a provider I forgot about, as I suspected existed, and one that effectively does exactly what the provider I was considering writing by hand would do.  That's sort of like having my cake and eating it too?  thanks :)